# mongoid embeds_one build howto

Tags: ruby, mongoid

Thanks for your time!

The code is simple(mongoid was used without rails):

```
require 'mongoid' # version 6.0.2

Mongoid.load!('mongoid.yml', :development)

class Office
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :owner
  embeds_many :addresses
end

class Owner
  include Mongoid::Document
end

class Address
  include Mongoid::Document
end
```

I could successfully call `office.addresses.build` as following.

```
office = Office.new
office.addresses.build
office.save
```

But when I call  `office.owner.build`, error pop up saying

```
embed_one.rb:23:in `<main>': undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

It's supposed to work in this way, right? Where is wrong.

```
puts office.owner.class # NilClass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After refresh myself from a sleep ...

I use `puts office.methods` to list all the methods `office` could invoke.

```
# Here's all the methods has *owner* in it
owner=
owner?
has_owner?
build_owner
create_owner
owner
```

`office.build_owner` is what i'm looking for!